Impala to hive sql conversion
I am trying to convert the below impala version hive query to hive.
Select load_date from abc.def Where (load_date between (case when date_part(‘day’, now()) <=5 from_timestamp(date_add(last_day(add_months (now(), -2)), 1),  ‘yyyy-mm-dd’) when date_part(‘day’, now()) >5 from_timestamp(date_add(last_day(add_months (now(), -1)), 1),  ‘yyyy-mm-dd’) End) and from_timestamp(now(), ‘yyyy-mm-dd’))
I tried by running the below but it is not throwing the same results.
SELECT load_date 
FROM abc.def 
WHERE load_date BETWEEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN day(current_date()) <= 5 THEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(add_months(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -2)), 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
        WHEN day(current_date()) > 5 THEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(add_months(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
    END 
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));

